# shutil.copy script not working

Tags: python

I wrote a script in python that was supposed to copy a bunch of files to system32 and then install them through cmd.

I can do it manually but I'm trying to make it automatic. This is what I wrote:

```
import shutil
import os
L = ['file1.type', 'file2.type'.... ]
dst = "C:\\Windows\\system32"
for f in L:
     shutil.copy(f, dst)
os.system("cmd command yada yada...")
```

And it doesn't work. I tried doing it step by step with idle and it worked fine. All the files are in the same directory as the script. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you execute the script? Do you get any error message? And what exactly is "yada yada"? ;)

Comment: I just double click it (using windows xp. The file is recognized as python related). Yada yada is the cmd command, which isn't relevant because the script already fails at the shutil copying method.

Comment: When you double click it, it's not run with Administrator privileges, and your user should not be able to write to `system32`. Right click "Run as Administrator" might work (not sure because of Python).

Comment: I have administrator privileges. And it doesn't matter, changing the destination to a different 'Test' folder didn't work either. I wrote it in sublime so I know it's not a syntax error (and like I said I checked everything with idle).

Comment: @yuvi your program is probably outputting a error. Try running it inside a console (run cmd.exe, cd to the program directory, and do "python program.py")

Comment: Did you try absolute paths to the files? It may be the script isn't executed in the directory you are in, but in the Python install path when double-clicked (I have something like this in mind, didn't work with Python on Win32 for ages).